# Tutorial on making a picture like this in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I always wanted to make a background like this but I could never find a tutorial on this. I also do not know what the effect is called so it makes it even harder for me to find.

[image]

This is the effect I am talking about, at the background. Does anyone know whats it called, or does anyone have a tutorial on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Starburst" tutorials:

- http://mintyferret.com/photoshop-tutorials/starburst-tutorial/
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJ9l9zDXTgE

[image: Examples of Starburst effect]

Comment: And if you want the fade-out effect for the outer regions of the lighter color, add a radial gradient with alpha 0 in the middle and the darker color at the edges.

Comment: This image is broken. Do you have the original that you could reupload?

Answer (score 3):

Granted that you want to do it in Photoshop, but you can also create the effect in GIMP with the Line Nova filter (Filters > Render > Line Nova...) ("Fill a layer with rays emanating outward from its center using the FG color"). It helps to make a small alteration to the script (line-nova.scm) to make it more useful by changing the "40" in:

```
  SF-ADJUSTMENT _"Number of lines"     '(200 40 1000 1 1 0 1)
```

to something like "10":

```
  SF-ADJUSTMENT _"Number of lines"     '(200 10 1000 1 1 0 1)
```

This would widen the filter's default range of lines (by extending the bottom end) to enable you to produce something more closely resembling your screenshot.